# Delete option not working in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Our Magento had crashed so i had to reinstall magento n the server again.

After installation now the Delete block across magento has stopped working. Cannot delete customer, static block or anything where there is delete option.

Does anyone has any solution for this. Tried installing Delete products extension but gives the same issue.

Edited:
Just Checked with the Remove option and it is also not working. So across all the site anything that has to do with Delete or Remove is a dead link

Comment: Can you share more about error? what does it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using old database,  please check base urls and clear database logs and clear cache memory.

After this if you still face issues please contact your hosting provider to install correct app of magento.

Thanks